# Why is command-line cat different than BBEdit?

Tags: command-line, audio, notepad++

In the film industry, it's common to have WAV audio files containing metadata in the iXML RIFF chunk.  One easy way to read this metadata is to open the WAV file in a text editor, like BBEdit or Notepad++ or even TextEdit.  But with command-line `cat` or `tail` it doesn't work, I just see garbage characters.  I'm using macOS 10.13 if it matters.  Why is `cat` different than these text editing apps?

Here is a sample file, with the iXML all the way at the bottom: http://www.gallery.co.uk/ixml/examples/usesEntireiXMLSpec.WAV

Comment: It's a binary file. Use `strings usesEntireiXMLSpec.WAV` to extract the text strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `cat` outputs the file, it outputs it byte-for-byte as-is without substituting spaces or dots or some other kind of substitution characters. So when it outputs the binary audio sample data earlier in the .WAV file, some of those bytes happen to match up with old school terminal control codes and "escape sequences" (sequences of bytes starting with the "ESC" character, which can be used to do things like change the text or background color, clear the terminal screen, and reposition the cursor within the terminal screen). Your terminal emulator (Terminal.app or iTerm2 or whatever) tries to honor those control codes and escape sequences, which throws off the way it normally displays text, and does so in unpredictable ways.

A lot of terminal-based tools have options for letting you deal with files that have some binary data mixed up with pure printable ASCII text. For example, `cat` has a `-v` option to make it substitute printable sequences in place of ASCII control characters. There's also `vis(1)`, `od(1)`, `hexdump(1)`, `strings(1)` and others. You could also use tools like `sed(1)`, `grep(1)`, and `awk(1)` to try to extract the ASCII XML data from the midst of the binary data in the file.

Of these options, I think `strings(1)` might be the most promising for you. It scans through the file looking for medium-to-long uninterrupted runs (strings) of printable ASCII characters, and automatically outputs any such strings it finds. So since XML is purely printable ASCII, `strings(1)` should print it all out while skipping all the binary audio data.

Comment: Indeed. See the comment I just added to the question. Good explanation by the way.